# Conditional expectation and coupled set of ODEs

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

How to find a coupled set of ODEs and initial conditions for the deterministic functions $a$ and $b$ such that
$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\int_{t}^{T} W^2(u)du} | \mathcal{F(t)}\right] = e^{-a(T-t) - \frac{b(T-t)}{2} W^2(t)}$$
Here, W is a Brownian motion.

This is a homework problem, but I missed the class and now struggling with getting it done, could anyone please explain me how to do this one?
Thank you